# Pass variable directly to $.post() function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following `$.post` syntax to retrieve json data from a database and I pass that to a function that appends them to a certain(!) div.

```
$.post("request.php", { var1:'var1', var2:var2, .. }, myownfunction, "json" );
```

Can I, from this line here above, pass a variable directly to my function?
Due to some glitch, I've created a bug in my script.

I have a lot of divs with the class 'x', and when a user selects one, its class is set to 'selected'. The function in the above post request only targets that: `$('div#selected')`, however, if by the time the response comes through the user selects another div, the data from the server gets appended to the wrong div.

I'd like to pass the id of the selected div to my function, so that there could be no confusion in what goes where. Is there a way to do that?

Right now, Im thinking of passing the id to the request.php and return it back as part of the json, but that would so not be elegant.

Comment: When do you send the POST request? On clicking of an element?

Comment: the divs contain images, when the user clicks on a div it gets enlarged and that's when I send the request, so that I can attach the information about the image to the div.. but while the user waits, he can click on another div....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to pass the id of the selected div to my function, so that there could be no confusion in what goes where. Is there a way to do that?

Yes, You can use [$.Proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass in the context of the clicked div. And access the id of the id using `this.id` inside the function.

```
$.post("request.php", 
                { var1:'var1', var2:var2, .. }, 
                $.proxy(myownfunction, elem), "json" );
```

Inside your function

```
function myownfunction( response )
{
....
    this.id // here will be the id of the element passed if it is the clicked div then you will get it here
....
}
```

Comment: no, no, no!  It's `this.id`, not `$(this).attr('id')`!  Please learn when _not_ to use jQuery.  You should also have just proxied `elem` rather than `$(elem)`.  As written you're calling the jQuery constructor twice for `elem` when there's no need to call it at all.

Comment: @Alnitak You are right infact i have mentioned this.id in my statement above the code but not in the actual code...

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the function call to an anonymous function you can pass whatever parameters you need.

```
$.post( 
    "request.php", 
    { var1:'var1', var2:var2, .. }, 
    function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        myownfunction( data, textStatus, jqXHR, myVariable );
    },
    "json" 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` you can use its `context` setting to explicitly set the callback's `this` value as required:

```
$.ajax('request.php', {
    type: 'POST',
    data: { ... },
    context: mydiv
}).done(myownfunction);

function myownfunction(data) {
    var id = this.id;     // extracting the element here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one as well! I've tried it, but it did not work. :S